# Best way to turn json csv into json object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a javascript object as follows:

```
[{name:'bla', ts:['a','b','c'], ms: ['d','e','f']}]
```

Without a bunch of temporary objects, what is the most efficient way I could go about turning it into an object as follows:

```
[{name:'bla',ts:'a',ms:'d'},
 {name:'bla',ts:'b',ms:'e'},
 {name:'bla',ts:'c',ms:'f'}]
```

I'm open to using something like lodash or underscore to accomplish this.

Comment: How are `name, ts and ms` related? Always 1 `name`? Is `ts` and `ms` of a similar nature?

Comment: yes, every unique name will have one record. ts and ms will be of the same size.

Comment: check this out, its not exactly the same, but the guy parses csv strings into objects using lodash...close enough for a start: http://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/7sza8shs/

Comment: @user6135815 Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly but works (and is easy to add 'extra' fields)

```
var a = [{name:'bla', ts:['a','b','c'], ms: ['d','e','f']}]

var result = [];
a.forEach(function(obj){
    obj.ts.forEach(function(item, index) {
        result.push({
            name: obj.name,
            ts: item,
            ms: obj.ms[index]
        })
    })
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks exactly like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{
  name: 'bla',
  ts: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ms: ['d', 'e', 'f']
}];

function parseArray(arr) {
  var result = [];
  arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.ts.length; i++) {
      result.push({
        name: obj.name,
        ts: obj.ts[i],
        ms: obj.ms[i]
      });
    }
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(parseArray(arr));
```